# Conversion of Piezoelectric coefficients

Tags: electrical-engineering

I am interested on simulating the converse Piezoelectric effect of materials and I have given the mechanical (Young's modulus and Poisson's ratio) and electric material properties (Electric Permittivity, Piezoelectric coupling matrix etc). However from the literature I got double index notation, I am struggling to convert double index notation to triple index notation.

The double index notation from literature is as follows:

Double index notation

$$\begin{bmatrix}
d_{11} & d_{12} & d_{13} & d_{14} & d_{15} & d_{16} \\
d_{21} & d_{22} & d_{23} & d_{24} & d_{25} & d_{26} \\
d_{31} & d_{32} & d_{33} & d_{34} & d_{35} & d_{36}
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 21.3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 21.3 & 0 & 0 \\
-2.6 & -2.69 & 3.65 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

I would like to convert them to Triple index notation used by some commercial software providers like Abaqus and MSC Marc etc and is written as follows:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
d_{11-1} & d_{11-2} & d_{11-3} \\
d_{22-1} & d_{22-2} & d_{22-3} \\
d_{33-2} & d_{33-2} & d_{33-3} \\
d_{12-2} & d_{12-2} & d_{12-3} \\
d_{23-2} & d_{23-2} & d_{23-3} \\
d_{31-2} & d_{31-2} & d_{31-3}
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & -2.6 \\
0 & 0 & -2.6 \\
0 & 0 & 3.65 \\
0 & 21.3 & 0 \\
21.3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Am I doing the conversion correctly? Are the values placed in correct positions?
Double Index = Triple Index = Coupling Matrix Value

$$\begin{alignat}{2}
d_{11} &= d_{11-1} &&= 0 \\
d_{21} &= d_{11-2} &&= 0 \\
d_{31} &= d_{11-3} &&= -2.6 \\
d_{12} &= d_{12-1} &&= 0 \\
d_{22} &= d_{22-2} &&= 0 \\
d_{32} &= d_{22-3} &&= -2.6 \\
\vdots \\
d_{16} &= d_{31-1} &&= 0 \\
d_{26} &= d_{31-2} &&= 0 \\
d_{36} &= d_{31-3} &&= 0 \\
\end{alignat}$$

Comment: You could try to use latex, enter `$d_{16}$` and you get $d_{16}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, I have edited them. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Caveat**:  I don't know the convention used in Marc.  The following is based on what I can recall about Abaqus and Ansys.

## Constitutive relations

The constitutive relations for *linear* piezoelectric materials are typically expressed in two forms:

1. the strain and electric field are the independent variables (called the stress-charge or e-form), and
2. the stress and electric field are the independent variables (called the strain-charge or d-form).

### Case 1 : stress-charge or e-form

The coupled equations in this case are
$$
\begin{align}
  \sigma_{ij} &= C_{ijkl} \varepsilon_{kl} - e_{mij} E_m \\
  q_i &= e_{ijk} \varepsilon_{jk} + D_{ij} E_j
\end{align}
$$

**Abaqus uses this form** because solid mechanics finite element models are more easily solved in strain-driven form.

### Case 2 : strain-charge or d-form

The above equations can also be written in the form
$$
\begin{align}
  \varepsilon_{ij} &= S_{ijkl} \sigma_{kl} + d_{mij} E_m \\
  q_i &= d_{ijk} \sigma_{jk} + D_{ij} E_j
\end{align}
$$
**Abaqus allows input of the coupling tensor $d$** because these numbers are easily converted into the $e$ tensor using the relation
$$
  e_{mij} = C_{ijkl} d_{mkl}
$$

## Converse piezoelectric effect

The converse piezoelectric effect is modeled by the first of the d-form equations while the direct effect is modeled by the second.  In particular, in the absence of stresses and external forces, the converse effect is written as
$$
\varepsilon_{ij} = d_{mij} E_m
$$

## Conventions

The symmetry of the strain tensor leads to various ways of representing the components in matrix form.  For example, the standard solid mechanics convention is
$$
  [\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}] = \begin{bmatrix} \varepsilon_{11} & \varepsilon_{22} & \varepsilon_{33} & \varepsilon_{23} & \varepsilon_{31} & \varepsilon_{12} \end{bmatrix}^T \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} \varepsilon_{1} & \varepsilon_{2} & \varepsilon_{3} & \varepsilon_{4} & \varepsilon_{5} & \varepsilon_{6} \end{bmatrix}^T
$$
The **Abaqus convention** is
$$
  [\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}] = \begin{bmatrix} \varepsilon_{11} & \varepsilon_{22} & \varepsilon_{33} & \varepsilon_{12} & \varepsilon_{31} & \varepsilon_{23} \end{bmatrix}^T \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} \varepsilon_{1} & \varepsilon_{2} & \varepsilon_{3} & \varepsilon_{4} & \varepsilon_{5} & \varepsilon_{6} \end{bmatrix}^T
$$

## Tensor d in matrix form

To express the coupling tensor in matrix form, let us expand out each term:
$$
\begin{align}
\varepsilon_{11} & = E_1 d_{111} + E_2 d_{211} + E_3 d_{311} \\
\varepsilon_{22} & = E_1 d_{122} + E_2 d_{222} + E_3 d_{322} \\
\varepsilon_{33} & = E_1 d_{133} + E_2 d_{233} + E_3 d_{333} \\
\varepsilon_{12} & = E_1 d_{112} + E_2 d_{212} + E_3 d_{312} \\
\varepsilon_{13} & = E_1 d_{113} + E_2 d_{213} + E_3 d_{313} \\
\varepsilon_{23} & = E_1 d_{123} + E_2 d_{223} + E_3 d_{323} 
\end{align}
$$
Using the **Abaqus convention**, we can write the above as
$$
\begin{align}
\varepsilon_{1} & = E_1 d_{11} + E_2 d_{21} + E_3 d_{31} \\
\varepsilon_{2} & = E_1 d_{12} + E_2 d_{22} + E_3 d_{32} \\
\varepsilon_{3} & = E_1 d_{13} + E_2 d_{23} + E_3 d_{33} \\
\varepsilon_{4} & = E_1 d_{14} + E_2 d_{24} + E_3 d_{34} \\
\varepsilon_{5} & = E_1 d_{15} + E_2 d_{25} + E_3 d_{35} \\
\varepsilon_{6} & = E_1 d_{16} + E_2 d_{26} + E_3 d_{36} 
\end{align}
$$
In matrix form,
$$
 \begin{bmatrix} \varepsilon_{1} \\ \varepsilon_{2} \\ \varepsilon_{3} \\ \varepsilon_{4} \\ \varepsilon_{5} \\ \varepsilon_{6} \end{bmatrix}
 = \begin{bmatrix} d_{11} & d_{21} & d_{31} \\ d_{12} & d_{22} & d_{32} \\ d_{13} & d_{23} & d_{33} \\ d_{14} & d_{24} & d_{34} \\ d_{15} & d_{25} & d_{35} \\ d_{16} & d_{26} & d_{36} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} E_1 \\ E_2 \\ E_3 \end{bmatrix}
$$
or
$$
  [\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}] = [\mathbf{d}]^T [\mathbf{E}]
$$
where
$$
  [\mathbf{d}] = \begin{bmatrix} d_{11} & d_{12} & d_{13} & d_{14} & d_{15} & d_{16} \\ d_{21} & d_{22} & d_{23} & d_{24} & d_{25} & d_{26} \\d_{31} & d_{32} & d_{33} & d_{34} & d_{35} & d_{36} \end{bmatrix} 
$$

## Double to triple index map

From the above we see that, **in Abaqus**, the matrix $[\mathbf{d}]$ is
$$
\begin{align}
  [\mathbf{d}] &= \begin{bmatrix} d_{111} & d_{122} & d_{133} & d_{112} & d_{113} & d_{123} \\ d_{211} & d_{222} & d_{233} & d_{212} & d_{213} & d_{223} \\d_{311} & d_{322} & d_{333} & d_{312} & d_{313} & d_{323} \end{bmatrix} \\
 & = \begin{bmatrix} d_{11} & d_{12} & d_{13} & d_{14} & d_{15} & d_{16} \\ d_{21} & d_{22} & d_{23} & d_{24} & d_{25} & d_{26} \\d_{31} & d_{32} & d_{33} & d_{34} & d_{35} & d_{36} \end{bmatrix} 
\end{align}
$$
Ansys (and possibly Marc) uses a different convention and the numbers will have to be changed accordingly.

If the constants in your initial matrix are arranged according to the **standard mechanics convention**, the above map changes to
$$
\begin{align}
  [\mathbf{d}] &= \begin{bmatrix} d_{111} & d_{122} & d_{133} & d_{123} & d_{113} & d_{112} \\ d_{211} & d_{222} & d_{233} & d_{223} & d_{213} & d_{212} \\d_{311} & d_{322} & d_{333} & d_{323} & d_{313} & d_{312} \end{bmatrix} \\
 & = \begin{bmatrix} d_{11} & d_{12} & d_{13} & d_{14} & d_{15} & d_{16} \\ d_{21} & d_{22} & d_{23} & d_{24} & d_{25} & d_{26} \\d_{31} & d_{32} & d_{33} & d_{34} & d_{35} & d_{36} \end{bmatrix} 
\end{align}
$$
You have to make sure that the convention used in the input 2-index matrix is known before you can write down the correct mapping.

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt response and detailed explanation. Its more clear for me now. Thanks again!